# How to connect MSSQL Server 2008 with Django

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I try to connect my local SQL Serer 2008 with Django. When I try to run the django server then this error is shown:

> django.db.utils.InterfaceError: ('IM002'. '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverCon)')

My connection string is:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': '',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server',
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your ODBC setup.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

run `pip install django-pyodbc-azure`  it will install latest `2.1.0.0` version

and in your `setting.py`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'name_of_database',
        'HOST': 'your_host',
        'USER': 'database_username',
        'PASSWORD': 'your password',

        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
                   }
    },
}
```

Comment: Because django-pyodbc-azure (2.1.0.0) depends on Django (>=2.1.0,<2.2)... means this is of no help if you're using modern versions of Django but working with legacy databases

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing the driver

```
'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server'
```

to

```
'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0'
```